# Summation Negative Sign Distribution (Series)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

[image]

The original summation is
$\sum (-1)^n\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$
and the explicit formula is ln|1+x|

I am confused as to how the negative sign is distributed to show that the input to f(x) is -1/3

could someone clear up what the process is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that for negative $x$ values, that $(-1)^nx^{n+1}$ will always be negative.

Because the series of interest is always positive, they inserted a negative to turn it into a form of$ \displaystyle \sum (-1)^n\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ where $x=-\frac{1}{3}$.

Then, once they had $x$, they were able to plug it into $f(x)$ to get $\ln|1-\frac{1}{3}|=\ln\frac{2}{3}$.

Finally, they reversed the negative, as they computed the negative of the series of interest, so the sum of the series of interest would be $-\ln  \frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: no, the answer key is correct

Comment: could you explain how will (-1)^n x^(n+1) always be negative?

Comment: so if $x$ is negative, then $(-1)^n x^{n+1} = (-1)^n (-1)^{n+1} |x|^{n+1}=(-1)^n (-1)^n (-1) |x|^{n+1} = (-1)1^n|x|^{n+1}=-|x|^{n+1}$ which is always negative

Comment: from what i am understanding, if the initial x in f(x) was -1/3 then you could separate out the negative to (-1)^n+1 * (1/3)^n+1 which would simplify to (-1)^n * (-1) * (1/3)^n+1 which be the same as the original summation besides the extra negative sign. Then you put a negative sign to cancel it getting -f(x)

Comment: exactly what they did